# Limit the recursion level in a Clojure repl

Tags: recursion, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

While working in the repl is there a way to specify the maximum times to recur before the repl will automatically end the evaluation of an expression. As an example, suppose the following function:

```
(defn looping []
  (loop [n 1]
    (recur (inc n))))

(looping)
```

Is there a way to instruct the repl to give up after 100 levels of recursion? Something similar to [*print-level*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*print-level*).

Comment: If you want to break out of evaluation: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html#clojure.repl/set-break-handler!

Comment: Is this similar to the default behavior of using Ctrl-C in a repl? In my scenario I do not notice a difference after calling set-break-handler!. When in infinite recursion and using Ctrl-C the repl is not interrupted and the recursion continues.

Answer (score 0):

I respectfully hope that I'm not ignoring the spirit of your question, but why not simply use a `when` expression? It's nice and succinct and wouldn't change the body of your function much at all (1 extra line and a closing paren).

Whilst I don't believe what you want exists, it would be trivial to implement your own:

```
(def ^:dynamic *recur-limit* 100)

(defn looping []
  (loop [n 1]
    (when (< n *recur-limit*)
      (recur (inc n)))))
```

Presumably this hasn't been added to the language because it's easy to construct what you need with the existing language primitives; apart from that, if the facility did exist but was 'invisible', it could cause an awful lot of confusion and bugs because code wouldn't always behave in a predictable and referentially transparent manner.

Comment: I'm hoping to protect against the accidental infinite recursion. It has happened that I do not correctly specify the terminal condition. The repl is then stuck in infinite recursion and I can't cancel it so I end up having to kill the whole repl, at the least. So it would be nice to specify a recursion level when I start the repl as a safe guard to prevent this.

Comment: this is impossible because `recur` compiles to a `goto`

Comment: Can you expand on this? I assume the print-level, and similar, work because the printer counts how many levels have been printed and stops at the specified level. In this case the written code is equivalent to the printer and so it is the one responsible for the counting, in a fashion similar to what @scott-lowe stated. Or is there something more to it?